# Bypass NULL <> NULL for an integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so in a Postgres DB -

```
id   dataset_id   entity_id   county_state_id   data
34   31           33413       341               JSOB object
35   31           33413       342               JSOB object
36   31           33413                         JSOB object
```

I want to insert or update this table based on if a record already exists in the table. I have written the following query to do so -

```
INSERT INTO entity (id, dataset_id, entity_id, county_state_id, data) 
SELECT
    nextval('id_seq'),
    (SELECT id FROM dataset WHERE name = 'Payer'),
    e.id,
    NULL
    jsonb_build_object
        ('a', a, 
        'b', b,
        'c', c,
        )
    from
entity e
JOIN payer p
ON p.id = e.id
ON CONFLICT (dataset_id, entity_id, data, county_state_id)
DO NOTHING;
```

I insert the following input into the table -

```
id   dataset_id   entity_id   county_state_id   data
37   31           33413                         JSOB object
```

I would expect the above SQL query to not update any records because this record already exists in the table. But it does insert a record. I suspect this is happening because `NULL <> NULL` and I am trying to insert a NULL into the `county_state_id` column. That is an integer column so I cannot insert an empty string into it, so I do not know how to get Postgres to recognize that the above record already exists in the table.

Comment: Yeah, but you could `INSERT` 0.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeah but I don't want to insert a zero because there is no `county_state_id` that is a 0.

Comment: Then create dummy record that has a `county_state_id` of  0 eg. 'no_county_state_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a filtered / partial unique [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) would be suitable here.

Actually, two indexes.

```
-- this takes care of non-null duplicates
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_entity_NON_NULL ON entity 
(dataset_id, entity_id, county_state_id);


-- this prevents duplicates when county_state_id IS NULL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_entity_NULL ON entity 
(dataset_id, entity_id)
WHERE (county_state_id IS NULL);
```

With this approach you don't need to use some special values, like `0` or `-1` instead of `NULL` values.

It is not clear for me from the question whether the `data` field should be included in the index, include it if necessary.

Comment: What would my `insert` or `on conflict` clause look like if I did it this way?

Comment: @Aaron, I think that your `INSERT` statement remains as it is. You would not be able to insert a second row with NULL `county_state_id` and repeating `dataset_id, entity_id`. The partial unique index would prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent duplicates, you need a unique index or constraint.  For this purpose, you need two of them:

```
-- handle not-NULL case
alter table t add constraint unqc_entity_4 unique (dataset_id, entity_id, data, county_state_id);

alter table t add constraint unqc2_entity_4 unique (dataset_id, entity_id, data, (case when county_state_id is null then -1 else id end);
```

Happily, `do nothing` applies to all constraints if none are specified, so you can phrase the insert as:

```
INSERT . . .
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=952dc0f1a3aa2941ce86c3f970d0d7f1) is a little db<>fiddle illustrating the concept.

Comment: I have a unique index that is why I am able to use the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: @Aaron . . . `NULL`s are tricky in this context but there is a pretty simple work-around.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I prefer to avoid using special values like `-1` instead of NULL. Postgres supports filtered / partial indexes, which I think fit here pretty well. See my answer.